Using another device or app: Prevent Moon Reader to lose the metadata
I will get a new computer in a few weeks or months, but for now, I only use my phone.
I was a happy Moon Reader user for a while, and edited tons of metadata, titles, cover, etc...
But now I became aware that Moon Reader doesn't really save metadata, and everything will be lost if I open the books in Calibre when I'll get my computer.
Is there a way to keep all this hard work ?
I noticed there is no good metadata editor on Android. Some rare apps edit a few metadata, or the cover, another app edit some other ones...
So that's hard to manually correct all the data.
Is there a way, though sync or anything, to keep the metadata ?
